# Data is not properly displayed in VueJS

Tags: html, vue.js, frontend

I have a small problem with my VueJS code, in the section "Output : Compressed GS1 Digital Link URI"

[image]

When there is no result, it should have nothing display like this (I have removed manually) :
[image]

I think I should put an if statement and only display the result if there is something.
Here is my code :

```
<input id="uncompressedDigitalLinkInput" class="digitalLink" type="text" v-model="uncompressedDigitalLinkInput">
<td class="charCount">{{uncompressedDigitalLinkInput.length}}</td>
```

What do you think ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Could you please edit the question to include a clear description of the current behaviour and the desired behaviour? Currently it is very unclear what you are asking. Make sure your description includes both what the user should see and how that relates to your data. Phrases like *'When there is no result'* don't tell us a great deal as we don't know exactly what you mean by that.