# (VueJS) How to remove an hint when there is nothing to display

Tags: html, vue.js

I have a small problem with my VueJS code, in the section "Output : Compressed GS1 Digital Link URI", you can see "{{compressedDigitalLink}}"

[image]

I've put this so when I clicked on the green button "Compressed", the section "{{compressedDigitalLink}}" is replaced by the result. 
[image]

But on Initialisation, there is no input, so no output, that's why the output section is replaced with "{{compressedDigitalLink}}". How can i remove it when the input is empty just like in the following screen ?
[image]

I think I should put an if statement and only display the result if there is something. Something like "v-if {{compressedDigitalLink}} == 0, don't display anything" ?

Here is my current code :

```
<input id="uncompressedDigitalLinkInput" class="digitalLink" type="text" v-model="uncompressedDigitalLinkInput">
<td class="charCount">{{uncompressedDigitalLinkInput.length}}</td>
```

What do you think ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: It's not clear from your question, from what you have posted, you don't need any if statement. while the uncompressedDigitalLinkInput is in the data and it's empty it won't show in the input textbox because its in the v-model.

Comment: Yes, a `v-if` would help to not display anything. The screenshots seem to be for a textbox, but the code example is a `td`, can you correct that?

Comment: Rather than posting the same question again you should just edit [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58255588/data-is-not-properly-displayed-in-vuejs) to include all the relevant information.